# Make update to WebSphere MQ Queue atomic

Tags: c#, ssis, queue, ibm-mq, bids

I am writing to an IBM WebSphere MQ Queue using an SSIS Script task written in C#. At the moment we use a couple simple loops to gather the information we need into a Dictionary object and then place the items, one by one, into the queue. We are now pulling from an SQL database, however, and I need to make these updates atomic.

Here is the code used to add the info to the Dictionary

```
   //add to list so we can weed out the duplicates
   if (!qContents.ContainsKey(retrievedMessage.Substring(0, 13)))
   {
        qContents.Add(retrievedMessage.Substring(0, 13), retrievedMessage);
   }
```

And here is where they are added to the queue. The MqPut method is used to post each item to the queue individually.

```
   //write out unique agent ids to consolidated queue
   foreach (string agentItem in qContents.Values)
   {
        MqPut(agentItem, _outputQueue);
   }
```

The whole block of code is wrapped in a try/catch/finally block, so I'm sure I will have to utilize that somehow, however I'm very new to WebSphere MQ and not sure how. Thx!

EDIT
Using the code from the answer below causes an exception to be thrown. Once the program gets to the MQMessage object's "put" method the MQ Exception "MQRC_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED" is thrown. This is _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you:

1. Read up a little bit about Messaging and then WebSphere MQ.
2. Look at the WebSphere MQ C# samples (found under `<mq_installation>\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base` folder).
3. Write some samples to make yourself comfortable.

To make it atomic you can use XA transaction feature of WebSphere MQ. You basically need to wrap your work in a Transaction scope. Sample pseudo snippet.

```
// Open queue
MQQueue q = MQQueueManager.AccessQueue( ...);

using (CommittableTransaction transScope = new CommittableTransaction())
{
      CommittableTransaction.Current = transScope;

      try
      {
          MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();

          // Add message contents
          mqMsg.Write(<data>);
          q.Put(mqMsg);

          transScope.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           transScope.Rollback();
           Console.Write(ex);
      }
      CommittableTransaction.Current = null;
    }
```

BTW, I am interested to know on `MqPut` method? Is this your own method or provided by some library?